# How Can I Load Multiple Scripts After Page Has Loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following code inside my HTML to load a JS file after page load.(DOMContentLoaded)

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
});
</script>
```

But I got several scripts to load and I have no idea how to implement this for multiple scripts.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.0.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>
```

Your help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could take a look at RequireJS. It is a JavaScript file and module loader. [What is RequireJs and how to use it](https://webkul.com/blog/what-is-requirejs-and-how-to-use-it/)

Comment: I would agree w/ Florent that there are libraries that manage this for you.  Otherwise, if you feel that that is overkill and you simply need to do this here, I'm not sure I understand the issue.  Could you not just use a loop to iterate over each `src` path and write an additional `script` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you could look at using a module loader.

If you want to do it without a module loader, then you have the right idea.  To keep the code easier to read/shorter, you could create an array of urls and iterate through them and appending a new script element for each.

```
    const jsFiles = [
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js',
        'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js',
        'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.0.0/bootstrap.min.js',
        'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8'
    ]
    jsFiles.forEach((item) => {
        const scriptEle = document.createElement('script');
        scriptEle.src = item;
        document.head.appendChild(scriptEle);
    })
```

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it seems to work just fine?  https://jsfiddle.net/nrayburn/nq871yob/5/